# Boto s3 error. BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

Why do I get this error with s3 and boto?

```
<Error><Code>BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou</Code><Message>Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.</Message><BucketName>rtbhui</BucketName><RequestId>84115D3E9513F3C9</RequestId><HostId>+3TxrA34xHcSx0ecOD3pseRnE+LwUv3Ax1Pvp3PFoE8tHfOcn5BXyihc9V/oJx2g</HostId></Error>

s3 = boto.connect_s3(parms['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], parms['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
bucket = s3.create_bucket(bucket_name)
k = Key(bucket) #bucket is global
k.key = bucket_path_and_key #'test/test/test'
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error message?

Comment: Stupid me...I always had a bucket name with a time stamp...this is the first one with out.

Comment: If you want access to an existing bucket, use s3.get_bucket(bucket_name) or s3.lookup(bucket_name).

Answer (score 6):

`BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou` errors will only be returned outside of the US Standard region. Inside the US Standard region (i.e. when you don't specify a location constraint), attempting to recreate a bucket you already own will succeed.

**Source**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, container with same name is already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a bucket you can just delete the last three lines of code and replace them with something like:

```
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket, validate = False)
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = key
```