# Referencing an existing S3 bucket to save file using Boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am following this [help guide](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/s3_tut.html), which explains how to save a file to an S3 bucket after creating it. I cannot find, however, an explanation of how to save to an existing bucket. More specifically, I am unsure how to reference a preexisting bucket. I believe replacing `create_bucket` with `get_bucket` does the trick. This allows me to save the file but because the documentation says that `get_bucket` "retrieves a bucket by name" I wanted to check here and make sure that it only retreives the bucket's metadata and does not does not download all of the contents of the bucket to my computer. Am I doing this right or is there a more pythonic way?

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket('mybucket')
from boto.s3.key import Key
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'foobar'
k.set_contents_from_string('This is a test of S3')
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd probably look pretty carefully at s3fs before taking a dependency on S3/Boto.  If you code for s3fs, your program should be portable to about anything that supports the POSIX filesystem API's.

Answer (score 5):

Your code looks reasonable.  The `get_bucket` method will either return a `Bucket` object or, if the specified bucket name does not exist, it will raise an `S3ResponseError`.

You could simplify your code a little:

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket('mybucket')
k = bucket.new_key('foobar')
k.set_contents_from_string('This is a test of S3')
```

But it accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: I originally tried your solution but I got this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346378/boto-s3-error-bucketalreadyownedbyyou Interestingly, I no longer get the error when I run your code. No idea what changed.

Comment: Do you know for sure/can you show that the `Bucket` object returned does not include the actual files in the bucket?

Comment: Well, I wrote the boto library.  I probably ought to know 8^)

Comment: Ok, so what's the answer? Is it downloading the bucket's contents or not? You never explicitly say.

Comment: It's not downloading the bucket's contents.  Buckets could have millions or even billions of objects in them.  Once you have the Bucket object, you can cycle through all of the objects in it by doing a ``for key in bucket:`` loop and boto will automatically handle the pagination of data for you.  But even here, you are only getting the metadata about the objects, not the objects themselves.