# S3 upload error in aws

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible, put

While uploading my file in the respective path of the bucket using ansible,it shows me error like this:

```
boto.exception.S3CreateError: S3CreateError: 409 Conflict  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Error>
    <Code>BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou</Code>
    <Message>Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.</Message>
    <BucketName>useast1`
```

here is my code:

```
      - name: S3 storage
        s3:
          region: "{{ region }}"
          bucket: "{{ bucketname }}"
          object: "{{ path }}/file.json"
          src: "home/ffn/{{ user_name }}/kp_out.json"
          mode: put
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boto s3 error. BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346378/boto-s3-error-bucketalreadyownedbyyou)

Comment: This is happening to me too.
I can tell you something about why this is happening. It has something to do with account access.

In my case the Ansible master is in AWS and while the same module call works for buckets under the same AWS account as the Ansible master but as soon as I try the same operation on a bucket on a different account (even if aws cli does and can PUT the object in those buckets on the SAME Ansible master) I get the same error as you:

boto.exception.S3CreateError: S3CreateError: 409 Conflict
BucketAlreadyExists
Why is ansible creating a bucket on a put operation?

Comment: Try using the shell command with aws cli and see what you get instead. I suspect this is yet another bug in Ansible. I'm using 2.0.2

Answer (score 2):

I have ansible version
ansible 2.2.1.0

I had the same problem, but after add region it worked

```
- name: copy to s3
  s3:
    bucket: <myBucket>
    mode: put
    aws_access_key: <myAccess>
    aws_secret_key: <mySecret>
    object: /<pathOnS3>/file.txt
    src: /home/user/file.txt
    permission: public-read
    region: eu-central-1
```